# Remove index.php from API url request

Tags: soap-api-v2

I need to remove `index.php` from the URL requests to the API. Currently API calls only work as the following...

```
/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl
```

I need it to load as

```
/api/v2_soap/?wsdl
```

Can any one give some idea.

Sadly I am not able to change where the script looks as it is coming from an integration on the Royal Mail website.

Comment: Did you have enable rewrite module in your server ? if so, enable `Web Server Rewrites` in Magento.

Comment: Did you got any solutions?